# Scrum Project Managment w/ Trac Integration

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum, trac

Currently we use Trac to manage all of our tickets (bugs, enhancements, and new projects). It lacks a nice ability to map out the projects, releases and do time estimations. Is there a good scrum project management system that would integrate with Trac to use the tickets we are already making?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of looking for something that could integrate with Trac, maybe you could use a Trac based solution. Trac has some plugins for Scrum but I'd suggest to check out [Agilo](http://www.agile42.com/cms/pages/agilo/) which is a nice Scrum oriented and polished version of Trac. This might be one of the best options in your case.

Answer (score 2):

would i be incorrect to assert that you should go through http://trac-hacks.org first and then elaborate here what, if anything, you didn't like about the plugins you found there? otherwise it's not possible to really say what is the best approach, when it is unknown whether you've scanned through the easiest paths.

Answer (score 1):

I work at a company that has completely embraced agile in our engineering organization, but we've done just fine using Jira for our issue management, even though it doesn't have any specific scrum features.  Our product manager keeps user stories (fleshed out with acceptance criteria) in his own organized backlog.  When the team picks them up for a sprint, he creates a Jira case and we put the case number on our board, along with all of the tasks (which aren't in Jira).

When bugs or feature requests come up (reported by customer support, netops, etc.), the PM prioritizes them just like any other user story.  If they're of an immediate nature, he'll put them straight onto the board, but he's hesitant to do so, knowing that's really a redirection of resources.  We leave some slack in our sprints to allow for such things, but if things get to hairy, we let him know that we'll have to drop a story, or not do the bugs.